# How to make the qgraphicsitem movable/not-movable dynamically?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I have many qgraphicsitem and I want to use a check box to set whether those qgraphicsitem are movable or not.
The only we I can think about now is to use setFlag(ItemIsMovable) for each one of the qgraphicsitem and use a signal from check box to trigger it.
Is there any better and more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood, each `QGraphicsItem` has special unique `QComboBox`.

So when you have many items you can `QSignalMapper` or try something like next(there are many ways to do this, I give example with small code):

```
QList<QPair<QCheckBox*,QGraphicsItem*> > pair;
//fill your list with all QCheckBox and QGraphicsItem pointers which you need

//do connection for each QCheckBox
for(int i = 0; i <pair.size(); i++)
{
    pair.at(i).first->setObjectName(QString::number(i));//it is a trick, objectName is our position in list
    connect(pair.at(i).first,SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)),SLOT(myslot()));
}
```

in myslot:

```
int index = sender()->objectName().toInt();
if(pair.at(index).first->isChecked())
   pair.at(index).second->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);//movable
else
    pair.at(index).second->setFlags(pair.at(index).second->flags() & ~QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable );//not movable
```

The most important thing that you shouldn't write every connection etc by hand, you do this in program. You can do something slightly different, but I showed you how to do this with ~10 lines, it is possible.